# Android emulator and device return different result from PHP script

Tags: android, http, emulation

I have a bit of a strange problem. I'm running a HTTP request from within my android application. It send 1 bit of data to a web server and then waits for the response, nothing special.

Now the problem i have is that when the request is ran from a actual device it operates perfectly, giving the expected result. When its ran from the emulator, for some reason the PHP script sends back a different result.

I have been able to confirm that the device and emulator are both sending the same data, does anyone know if the emulator and device do anything different??

Comment: How can we know without codes, log, etc?

Comment: Add Android Code, Add Logcat, Add PHP Script. Then we can help. Nobody is a magician here to tell without any codes and logcat!

Comment: Turns out that the wrong information was actually being sent to the PHP script somehow.